# Pyinstaller app not getting microphone permission works fine with terminal

Tags: python, pyinstaller, macos-big-sur

Our script which uses the following libraries

```
import os
import sys
from random import sample as rand_sample
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from gtts import gTTS
from Levenshtein import ratio
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import platform
import webbrowser
from hashlib import sha1
from getpass import getuser
from socket import gethostname
import clipboard
import wavio
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf
import speech_recognition as sr
import wave
from playsound import playsound
from difflib import get_close_matches
import json
import urllib.request
from ssl import _create_unverified_context

class audio():
def __init__(mic,path):
    mic.fs=44100
    mic.path=path
def recordAudio(mic,time):
    recording=sd.rec(int(time*mic.fs),samplerate=mic.fs,channels=1)
    sd.wait()
    return recording
def save(mic,filename,recording):
    wavio.write(mic.path+filename,recording, mic.fs, sampwidth=2)
def play(mic,filename):
    data,fs = sf.read(mic.path+filename,dtype='float32')
    sd.play(data,fs)
    status=sd.wait()
def getText(mic,filename): #use google speech recongition to convert
    # print (mic,filename)
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    hellow=sr.AudioFile(mic.path+filename)
    with hellow as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration = 1)

        audio = r.record(source)
    try:
        s = r.recognize_google(audio)
        return(s)
    except:
        return ('error reading speech...')
    return ""
```

Can access microphone when run the app bundle via terminal (Permission is granted for it screenshot attached)

[image]
however when we package it using pyinstaller using this command

`pyinstaller --noupx --onedir --onefile --windowed interview.spec  interview.py`

It is successfully converted into an app and we can launch it with double click. But it cannot access micriphone, nor does it asks for permission. Do we have to add some specific python snippet to ask for permission? Looking forward to your suggestions and help as i am clueless in this.

System:
macOS Big Sur
Version 11.5.2

Comment: What specific code is used to access the microphone? Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Try running the bundle from terminal, It will show the error logs and update your question with the same, it will be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you i have added more info, with bundled app it works fine when run via terminal

Comment: for the `pyinstaller` command, did you have to do anything extra (in your .spec file?) to get `sounddevice` to be correctly bundled? I'm debugging how to fix `No module named 'sounddevice' ModuleNotFoundError` from the terminal with PyInstaller

Answer (score 0):

In the end just ended up writing a script and putting an icon on it, so user can double click on it and start using the app. Though in Big Sur you have to do chmod 755 to it in almost every new pc it is copied to.

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )
cd "${DIR}"
./interview.app/Contents/MacOS/interview
```

Comment: Did you eventually find out what the issue was? I seem to be having a similar issue with my PyInstaller app.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already have `interview.spec`.

**Solution**.
if so, in my case though, the solution was adding following info_plist item in interview.spec

```
app = BUNDLE(
    exe,
    name='YOUR_APP_NAME.app',
    icon='YOUR_ICON_NAME.icns',
    bundle_identifier=None,
    info_plist={'NSMicrophoneUsageDescription':'Reason for microphone access'},
)
```

and then execute `pyinstall interview.spec` and `create-dmg`.
now, you have a dmg for your app then install and run it. I followed this [article](https://medium.com/@jackhuang.wz/in-just-two-steps-you-can-turn-a-python-script-into-a-macos-application-installer-6e21bce2ee71)

The first time the app is launched, a dialog box will appear asking if you want to allow the app to access the microphone.

**Note**.
Reference: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html?highlight=info.plist#spec-file-options-for-a-macos-bundle

My Environment: MacOS 13.2.1